# Mac Mail: Add other message as attachment

Tags: macos, mac, mail.app, email, attachments

I'd like to add other mail message as an attachment to a new one but Mail (On OSX Lion) does not allow me to do that.

Any workaround?

Gil

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Attaching other Messages in Mail.app (OS X Lion)

1. Create a new message (⌘N)
2. Return to your inbox
3. Click and hold on the message you want to attach until it turns into a letter icon [image: Letter Icon]
4. *(Still holding down)* drag and drop the icon into the new message window

Repeat steps 2 through 4 for as many messages as you want to attach.

Comment: You can't put enough emphasis on step #3. You really have to wait a bit til the icon appears. If you drag too early you just start selecting several mails.

Answer (score 2):

This might help in your case:

1. Select the email message you want to send as an attachment.
2. Click on File then **Save As** and select the format **Raw Message Source**
3. Open a new email message and add the raw source file as an attachment (either copy and paste or insert).

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking to do is "forward" an email...

Answer (score 0):

What I did was , composed a new email , went back to my inbox and dragged and dropped the required emails into my composed email .

I think it worked